# Is there a proof of axiom supremum for real number?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

If A$\subset R$ bounded above then the supremum exists..
I cant find the proof anywhere

Comment: is that not the definition of supremum and the concept of axiom, an axiom cannot be proven?

Comment: If you develop a theory of real numbers, say for example via Dedekind cuts, then the axiom of supremum becomes a theorem with a relatively easy proof. Most modern texts follow axiomatic approach to real numbers and  hence such a proof is not so common.

Comment: @user29418: You can abstractly define $\mathbb{R}$ as a field satisfying the supremum axiom and other properties (in which case you don't have to prove anything) OR you define the real numbers in a constructive way (for example by identifying Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$ that 'go to the same limit'). In the latter case you can prove that the real numbers satisfy the supremum axiom explicitly.

Comment: Also minor nitpick. Your $A$ needs to be non-empty.

Comment: You can read the proof in Strichartz The Way of Analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can prove that if a subset $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ is bounded above then it has a supremum, according to the definition of $\mathbb{R}$ you are dealing with: the fact that taken $A\subset \mathbb{R}$, $B\subset \mathbb{R}$, where $A,B\neq\emptyset$ such that for every $a\in A$, $b\in B$, $a\leq b$, there exists $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall a\in A:\forall b\in B: a\leq\xi\leq b$, can be put as an axiom, making $\mathbb{R}$ a (*the* one and only up to isomorphism) complete ordered field that we want it to be.

In this setup, let $\emptyset\neq E\subset\mathbb{R}$ bounded above; $E$ and $K=\{\text{upper bounds of}\ E\}$ are both nonempty sets satisfying the statement above. This of course means that the supremum exists; remembering the definition of supremum ($\operatorname{min}$ of something), you can check unicity.

Comment: This is replacing one axiom by another. And essentially it is an axiomatic approach to the real numbers.

Comment: It's not perfectly clear to me what the op is asking: it's very common to state the continuity axiom in the form known by @zainudin in elementary analysis textbooks, in order to avoid this elementary proof.

Comment: Well then the burden shifts to proving the result you mention (this was the result which Dedekind established as part of his theory of real numbers).

Answer (score 1):

This is an expansion of my comment (to the question).

---

Following Dedekind we say that

> **A real number** is a subset $A$ of the set of rationals (ie $A\subseteq\mathbb{Q} $) with the following properties:
>
> - $A$ as well as $\mathbb {Q} - A$ is non-empty ie $\emptyset \neq A\neq\mathbb {Q} $.
> - If a rational number lies in $A$ then all the smaller rationals also lie in $A$.
> - If a rational number lies in $A$ then there is a greater rational also lying in $A$ ie $A$ has no greatest member.

Without going into details we focus on the part needed here. *A real number $A$ is said to be less than another real number $B$, written as $A<B$, if $A\subset B$*. In what follows usual capital Roman letters like $A, B, C$ denote real numbers ie sets of rationals with the specific properties listed above and letters like $\mathcal{A, B, C} $ represent sets of real numbers.

Let's come back to your axiom:

> **Completeness axiom**: Let $\mathcal{A} $ be a non-empty set of real numbers which is bounded above ie there is a real number $K$ such that $A\leq K, \forall A\in \mathcal{A} $. Then there is a real number $M$ such that no member of $\mathcal{A} $ exceeds $M$ and any real number less than $M$ is exceeded by some member of $\mathcal{A}$. This number $M$ is called the supremum of $\mathcal{A} $ and denoted by $M=\sup\, \mathcal{A} $.

**Outline of proof**: Consider the set $M\subseteq \mathbb {Q} $ defined by $$M=\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal{A}} A$$ ie $M$ is the union of all the members of $\mathcal{A} $ (note that by definition the members of $\mathcal{A} $ are sets of rationals and hence their union makes sense). Show that the set $M$ satisfies all the three properties of a real number mentioned earlier. This part is easy and you will need the fact that $\mathcal{A}$ is bounded above.

Next one needs to show that $A\leq M$ ie $A\subseteq M$ for all members $A\in\mathcal {A} $. This is obvious as $M$ is the union of all such $A$.

And finally let $N$ be any real number less than $M$ ie $N\subset M$. And then we have to show that there is some member $A\in\mathcal{A} $ such that $N<A$ ie $N\subset A$. This is not so difficult to show and one can do it via contradiction.

Comment: For future readers, note that the two different approaches to constructing the real numbers, namely Dedekind cuts and Cauchy sequences, are actually fundamentally different, despite yielding the same result when applied to the rationals. This can be seen by observing that Dedekind cuts can be used to obtain the completion of any linear order, while Cauchy sequences can be used to obtain the completion of any 'metric'-space (satisfying [the metric-space axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Definition) except with $R$ relaxed to being an ordered field). Rationals happen to be both.

Comment: So it can be instructive to also prove the supremum axiom for the Cauchy sequence construction. This is an exercise that is non-trivial but not that hard.

Comment: @user21820: will update my answer to include the proof using Cauchy sequences after some time.

Comment: Oh I didn't mean to suggest that you need to include that in your post. After all, this particular question is not a great one...